# Facing spam traffic issues to website

Tags: html, .htaccess, spam-prevention, honeypot

I am facing spam issue from last 1 year.  My website representing to software industry and developed in core PHP with HTML5.

I have tried below steps to resolve the issues. One solution I have not tried that is Captcha because I don’t watch any captcha in website where customer face some hesitation to fill the forms. We are also using Infusionsoft API to submit the forms.

Below steps I have executed:

**Step #1: Hidden fields in forms**

Declared one additional form fields and hide them with CSS. On form submission, block the form submission, if any of those hidden fields have values populated.
 In addition, changing the hidden field names periodically.
 Why recommended:
A spam robot will probably fill out each field it encounters. Works well, unless the spam robot is able to understand CSS and script.

**Step #2:  IP restriction**

We are saving the IP address & timestamp of each rejected submission in database.
If we receive a form submission using wrong fieldnames, don’t display the form at all – we just show a note that this IP address will remain blocked for the next few minutes. 
 Blocking the users IP for continuous hits. This will be configurable based on [number of hits].

**Step #3:  Ghost Referrer Spam**

Ghost Spam can only be stopped within Google Analytics with filters. I have tried all the steps suggested here Valid Hostname Filter
Step #4:  Crawler Referrer Spam
Implemented rules in  .htaccess file or with filters. Another technique we have used is a Deflector, which redirects the traffic back to where it came from.

I am also thinking to implement DNS level where we can isolate traffic from certain countries. If traffic arrives from a country that we do not want then the user is asked to do a second level authentication essentially preventing spam.

What do you think about this?

Please provide your expert answer, if we have any other idea?

Comment: Have you seen/used http://www.projecthoneypot.org/?

Comment: Regarding your DNS country restriction, cloudflare can handle this very easily for you. You may want to try it out, it is free and requires a few DNS changes. Just make sure only traffic can reach you through cloudflare.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with InfusionSoft

Comment: Any other thoughts. cloudflare and other third party can be used but all our website traffic will go from cloudflare , which i don't want. Please suggest any other way if we have.